# C# XML Deserialization fails when unicode character code present in middle of element name

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, .net-6.0

See reproduction here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CAV0vV

A "x0020" in the xml element name causes the property to come back as null.

Is there any way to get the expected behavior to occur?

Comment: It looks like you have a solution in your fiddle, in replacing the bad string with empty string. What else are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to deserialize the existing xml without formatting it first, since there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with it. This is a pared down version of what I'm actually doing, which is reading large xml data generated by another program. The added operation to use regex to replace any 'x####' could get expensive.